# Sort rows in a table in excel

Tags: excel

I have a large table with lots of "ORDERS" that go by numbers, each has multiple numbered "STEPS" (not necessarily equal in all orders). Each step has a "STATUS" which is one of two: "In process" or "completed".

I want to create a column that tracks each orders' step, and if they are all completed it will mark the order in all of it's rows as "FINISHED".

I tried formula Array but I can't think about something that worked.

**EXAMPLE of a Desired outcome:** (First row and column are belong to Excel's bar)

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **ORDER number** | **STEP number** | **STEP Status** | **ORDER STATUS** |
| 2 | 179 | 001 | completed | FINISHED |
| 3 | 179 | 002 | completed | FINISHED |
| 4 | 179 | 003 | completed | FINISHED |
| 5 | 179 | 004 | completed | FINISHED |
| 6 | 192 | 001 | In process |  |
| 7 | 192 | 002 | completed |  |
| 8 | 192 | 003 | completed |  |
| 9 | 192 | 004 | In process |  |
| 10 | 192 | 005 | In process |  |
| 11 | 202 | 001 | completed | FINISHED |
| 12 | 202 | 002 | completed | FINISHED |
| 13 | 202 | 003 | completed | FINISHED |
| 14 | 202 | 004 | completed | FINISHED |
| 15 | 202 | 005 | completed | FINISHED |
| 16 | 202 | 006 | completed | FINISHED |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D2, formula should be `=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, C:C, "completed") = COUNTIF(A:A, A2), "FINISHED", "")`. Then copy that formula down column D.

Comment: Thanks for commenting - I can see the logic, but the formula has a "too many arguments for format" error.

Comment: Apologies, that first COUNTIF should be COUNTIFS, editing answer now

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I appreciate your answer